# Same data object gets created every-time in django-sqlite3?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, validation

I am working on a Django project of scraping some data and storing it in the SQLite database:-
*models.py file*

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

class News(models.Model):
    title         =   models.CharField(max_length=120)
    datess        =   models.CharField(max_length=120)
    linkss        =   models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug          =   models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug and self.title:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(News, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "news"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/news/{self.slug}"
```

Here's the *views.py file*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import News
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.db.models import Q
# For scraping part
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def news_list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # fOR scraping part - START::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    response = requests.get("http://www.iitg.ac.in/home/eventsall/events")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
    cards = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "newsarea"})

    iitg_title = []
    iitg_date = []
    iitg_link = []
    for card in cards[0:6]:
        iitg_date.append(card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ndate"}).text)
        iitg_title.append(card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ntitle"}).text.strip())
        iitg_link.append(card.find("div", attrs={"class": "ntitle"}).a['href'])
    # fOR scraping part - END::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    # fOR storing the scraped data directly into the dtatbase from the views.py file - START---------------------------------------------------------------
    for i in range(len(iitg_title)):
        News.objects.create(title = iitg_title[i], datess = iitg_date[i], linkss = iitg_link[i])
    # fOR storing the scraped data directly into the dtatbase from the views.py file - END-----------------------------------------------------------------

    queryset = News.objects.all()   #Getting all the objects from the database

    search_query = request.GET.get('q')
    if search_query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains = search_query) |
            Q(description__icontains = search_query)
        )

    paginator = Paginator(queryset, 5)  #Adding pagination
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    queryset = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {
       'object_list': queryset
    }

    return render(request, 'news_list.html', context)
```

Each time I refresh the webpage the same objects get created, again and again, I tried some approach to check if the data is already present in the database, but I am unable to figure out the exact `condition` to do these.

Comment: Maybe you can make the fields unique?

Comment: Yes, it will happen since the given code doesn't have any validation to check any unique or existence condition.

Comment: @Snackoverflow I tried doing that but still didn't work.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, That's what I am unable to figure out, like where and how to add that condition?

Comment: add unique=True in slug field in models

Comment: @CharanjitSingh, that's raising this error:-
`IntegrityError at /news/
UNIQUE constraint failed: news_news.slug`

Comment: because there are duplicated slugs, you can add this restriction to handle unique constraints

Comment: Now track why it's giving integrity error while running the server to track double creation of same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your data that used to create a object are the same on each iteration , you should use this function `get_or_create` instead of `create` as ducumented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). it will search through database with parameters passed on `kwargs`. if it does not exists , django will create a new object for you. in your example the code should be as follows:

```
for i in range(len(iitg_title)):
        News.objects.get_or_create(title = iitg_title[i], datess = iitg_date[i], linkss = iitg_link[i])
```